# PEAR Image_Graph XAxis coordinate orientation

Tags: php, graph, label, orientation, pear

I'm making a graph using PEAR [Image_Graph](http://pear.php.net/package/Image_Graph/docs) and the bottom coordinates labels are dates.  Instead of the labels (dates) displaying horizontally, I'd like them to display vertically - or maybe at a slight angle, so they aren't all on top of each other.  However, I'm not sure if this is possible and I can't seem to find anything in the documentation for this.

Does anyone have any experience with this or know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image_Graph does not support rotating text on an axis, sorry.